# how can I run an initializer from the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, console, initialization, rails-console

I've got an initialization file `config/initializers/linkedin.rb` that sets up the Linkedin gem so that my app can connect to the LinkedIn service and run queries. I'm now testing out some new features and I want to use the console for this. My problem - asside from being a newb and not understanding the console very well yet - is that I can't access the variables that are initialized in `config/initializers/linkedin.rb`.

Any ideas on how to use the application initializers from within the console so that I don't have to run this by hand every time?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this looks like a BUOK (Bad User On Keyboard) error. I was typing `Linkedin` instead of `LinkedIn`. When I get the capitalization right, I see that the LinkedIn gem is initialized. So, it looks like `config/initializers/*.rb` are being run when you drop down into the console.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
load "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/your_file.rb"
```