# ruby-on-rails initializer not working in irb, but working when running app normally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, config

I have an idea to write up a small redis wrapper lib for my side project.
everything has been looking just great so far.
now, I'm trying to bring polish to my configuration, which I'm a little inspired by configuration block code from airbrake project, [reference article here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block)

From the start, I got myself rolling immediately to write up the wrapper class and I managed to do so in a timely manner. Up to this point, what I need to do is I'd like to be able to test my configuration code block (config/initializers/redis_cli.rb) in irb or pry.
I'm not sure why my initialisation code, which is placed under rails project config/initializers, is not working in such debugging console environment.

as soon as I instantiated my RedisCli class in the console as to =>

```
 RedisCli.new
```

I got an error saying that 
"NoMethodError: undefined method `host' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/admin/rails_projects/redis_app/lib/redis_cli.rb:44:in`redis_wrapper_options'"

In contrast, it works just great when running on internal web server, web brick.
It seems like my RedisCli initializer didn't get loaded properly in irb.

here is my code:

lib/redis_cli.rb

```
class RedisCli


  attr_accessor :host,:port,:db,:url,:queue

  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration)
  end  

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :host,:port,:db,:queue

    def initialize

    end
  end 

  def initialize(options={})
    options = redis_wrapper_options(options)
    @host = options[:host]
    @port = options[:port]
    @db = options[:db]
    @queue = options[:queue]
  end

  def url
    @url ||= [@host,@port].reject(&:blank?).join(":") if @url.blank?
    @url       
  end

  def lpush(klass,args)
    redis = Redis.new(:url => url)
    msg = { 'class' => klass,'args' =>  [args],'jid' => SecureRandom.hex(12), 'retry' => true, 'enqueued_at' => Time.now.to_f }
    redis.lpush(@queue,JSON.dump(msg))
  end

  def redis_wrapper_options(overrides = {})      
    {
      :host  => RedisCli.configuration.host,
      :port => RedisCli.configuration.port,    
      :db => RedisCli.configuration.db,        
      :queue   => RedisCli.configuration.queue

    }.merge(overrides || {}).delete_if { |key, value| value.nil? }
  end

end
```

and my initializer:

config/initializers/redis_cli.rb

```
RedisCli.configure do |config|
  config.host    = 'redis://localhost'       
  config.port    = '6379'       
  config.db      = ''       
  config.queue   = 'queue:default'                      
end
```

Could anyone bring me to light on this?

Comment: In your def self.configure method, have you tried changing self.configuration to @configuration ||= Configuration.new (for your memoization)? Using self vs @ will reference the variable in different ways and can cause this. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693243/instance-variable-self-vs) Is a good explanation of what occurs for self vs @.

Comment: Thanks Chris.
I made change following to your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. still getting the same error, "NoMethodError: undefined method host' for nil:NilClass". any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553944/init-some-variables-when-opening-rails-console?lq=1 might be helpful, although I've found that my initializers are *sometimes* run, but not always, on `rails c`. I have no explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Are you typing `irb`, or something like `bundle exec rails c`?

Comment: Hi Brad, I usually run "rails c"
I also tried 'bundle exec rails c' right after your post, neither seems to work though. however, you've brought me an idea this's most likely a misconfiguration problem application-wide.
I'll try the code on a freshly created project. let's see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me as well on Rails 5.1.4

The only thing that worked for me was to completely exit `Terminal.app`, relaunch `Terminal.app`, and then re-run `rails c`.  Rails Console took about 4-5 seconds longer to initialize than it did before I restarted terminal.  It appears that there is some sort a caching going on but that is just a hunch.